# System.NotSupportedException: while removing node nodes from XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML which is bound to `GridView`. In a grid view column I have a button to delete the row. but I keep getting:

> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.

```
protected void Remove(string itemValue)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/ReportConfig.xml"));
    doc.Descendants("Report")
          .Where(p => (string)p.Attribute("ID") == itemValue)
    .FirstOrDefault().Remove();
}
protected void GridView1_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName != "Delete") return;
    Remove(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
}
```

And the XML that I am trying to edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Reports>
  <Report ID="1">
    <Name>Induction Status</Name>
    <Query>xyz</Query>
    <Details>User List</Details>
  </Report>
</Reports>
```

Comment: Normally this error occurs when you try to remove the root node of an xml.  Net will not allow a remove which will create an empty xml object.  I suspect it will also occur if your are getting a null from the "Where".  Is itemvalue a string or an integer?

Comment: itemvalue is numeric value, also am i not getting only the Descendants of root by using   doc.Descendants("Report")?

Comment: There is no reason with the xml you  posted that Descendants will not work.  Make sure you are using the correct xml file.  Put a beak point on Descendants and then hover over doc and make sure the document contains "Report".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `Where()` condition is not met, `FirstOrDefault()` returns the default which is `null`, and then `Remove()` will throw the exception because it cannot work on a `null` reference.

According to your code, when `e.CommandArgument.ToString()` is `"1"`, then your code will work and you will end up with the XML `<Reports />`. But when `e.CommandArgument.ToString()` is any value other than `"1"`, then your code will throw the exception. Change it to `.FirstOrDefault()?.Remove()` to avoid the exception:

```
doc.Descendants("Report")
   .Where(p => (string)p.Attribute("ID") == itemValue)
   .FirstOrDefault()?.Remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, as suggested used "?" to handle null values now there is no exceptions but it return empty string even though the ID attribute is available. I suspected issue could be with XML and got it validated. Although now I have exported XML data to DB and working on that, but still need to understand what could be reason behind this issue.

Comment: Like I said, your code will work with the XML that you posted in your question, so the problem is not the XML. Perhaps the `e.CommandArgument` is not exactly "1", put a breakpoint and check the value. Or perhaps the XML file has an issue, maybe incorrect encoding. You can post the file somewhere where we can download it and check for you. Or you can recreate it. Open it in NotePad, select all the text and copy it, create a new text file in NotePad, paste the text, select Save As, and save it using the UTF-8 encoding. Now test with the new file and see if issue is resolved.